# Make this function repeat using runOnUiThread to update textview location

Tags: java, android, function, repeat

I trying to make my textView appear in different place of the screen every minute or two (delay is not important). I've seen people are suggesting I use runOnUiThread to make a timer repeat the random function and the update the UI.

I'm really struggling getting my head around these different threads, just wondering if anyone could give me an example? Or should I research using something different?

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);  
    Random r = new Random();

    int x = r.nextInt(350 - 100);
    int y = r.nextInt(800 - 100);

    textView.setX(x);  
    textView.setY(y);
}
```

Comment: You have to use runOnUiThread to update your TextView, but do not run your timer on this thread! Use a new Thread to shedule or an SheduledExecutorService: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
public void doInback()
    {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Try the code that you want to repeat


                doInback();
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

just call the method where you want to use.

Comment: If this method is called will it not repeat the function just once?

Answer (score 0):

Create the runnable and the handler below

```
 private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {         
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
};
Handler handler = new Handler() {       
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {            
        //change the text position here         
        this.postDelayed(runnable , TIME_OUT_MS);
        }
    };
```

The TIME_OUT_MS is the time out you want in milliseconds.

And put this on the OnCreate() method of the activity

```
    Thread thread =new Thread(runnable );
     thread.start();
```

Comment: Ok, excuse my ignorance, but where exactly do I put the last "Thread thread =new Thread(runnable ); thread.start();" bit?